# Where does Texan English derive its l-vocalization?

Tags: english, phonetics, dialects, american-english

My English teacher grew up in Texas and unsurprisingly her native dialect is Texan English. I noticed that when intervocalic /l/ is followed by /i/, the /l/ is elided and /y/ takes its place. For example, "million" is pronounced "miyyon" and "bill you" is pronounced "biyyou". I wanted to see if this feature was also present in SAE, as it could explain the origin. Texan English seems to derive a lot of features from SAE.

According to Wikipedia, l-vocalization is any case where /l/ becomes a vowel or semivowel. However, most examples that come up when I try to find information on "English l-vocalization" are cases where dark l is elided or replace with /w/. So, either the feature in my teacher's dialect is not actually an example of l-vocalization, or I'm just terrible at using google.

So, my question is this: Is the /l/ to /y/ feature derived from SAE? If it is, where could I find more information on this sort of topic in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be **Mexican Spanish**.

In my close-to-GAE dialect, the word "million" has only two syllables—that is, it has `/j/`, not `/i/`, in the middle. Phonetically, this `/lj/` is often realized as `[ʎ]`, blending the lateral-ness of `/l/` with the palatal-ness of `/j/`.

Spanish classically had a phonemic distinction between `/ʎ/` and `/j/`. But a famous and distinctive feature of Mexican Spanish (which is now pretty much universal in other dialects too) has always been *yeísmo*: merging them both into `[j~ʝ]`.

So I would attribute the Texan shift, `/lj/ [ʎ]` → `[j~ʝ]`, to the influence of Mexican *yeísmo*. Midwestern English (a bit to the north) and Southern American English (a bit to the east) are both farther from Mexico and thus don't show the same shift.